# How get html from user via textarea tag in correct formate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I am getting html form user through html . After getting html i am loading it into htmlaglity via HtmlDocument.LoadHtml() function. Here is html code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
     <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is c# code:

```
HtmlDocument hd = new HtmlDocument();

        hd.LoadHtml(html);
        string st_debug; 
        foreach (var item in hd.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr"))
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode secNode in item.ChildNodes)
            {
                st_debug = secNode.InnerHtml;
            }
        }
```

The problem is it is returning me data like "   " instead of 'sometext' and when i remove extra space between tags like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Some text
</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

it is giving me correct output. What is the solution of this because user will just copy the html and past as it is.
I have write the same code in winform but getting the html from browser control and that works perfect. is there any problem while loading html ? please help

Answer (score 0):

Check encoding settings while getting the documents.

Use tools such as postman to validate your requests.

Reference

Postman , chrome addon ,
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: encoding is ''content="text/html; charset=UTF-8", now what ?